# psexec %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: c#, windows, remote-access, jobs

This is the Code I am using to run a exe file which is on a remote server. I deployed the console application with the following code in my Web server to call the exe which is on the remote server. But I am getting the error "psexec %1 is not a valid Win32 application". I tested this code in my local machine it works fine...but it is not working on the server.

```
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\PsTools");
        info.FileName = @"C:\PsTools\psexec.exe";
        info.Arguments = @"\\" + "MyComputerName" + @" -h D:\Idealake\Schedulers\SBIHangFireConsole\bin\Debug\SBIHangFireConsole.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = Process.Start(info);
```

Server Details --

Kernel version:            Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, Multiprocessor Free
Product type:              Standard Edition
Product version:           6.3
Service pack:              0
Kernel build number:       9600
Registered organization:
Registered owner:          Windows User
IE version:                9.0000
System root:               C:\Windows
Processors:                4
Processor speed:           2.5 GHz
Processor type:            AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6380
Physical memory:           2 MB
Video driver:              VMware SVGA 3D

PsTools Version in this package: 2.45

Comment: Have you verified that powershell is installed on the server?

Comment: @RonBeyer psexec isn't powershell, it's a utility

Comment: @HemanthVatti `psexec` is a utility that must be installed on the server. It's not part of Windows. It's not needed either. You can use Powershell to connect to a remote machine and execute anything you want.

Comment: Yes There is not need to install poweshell. I didn't install it in my local machine but it is running successfully...

Comment: Why are you using `psexec` then? `psexec` is *not* Powershell, it's a Sysinternals utility

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  The cahllenge is I have to call a exe file from my C# code. Is it possible to include powershell inside C# to do that. If yes can you give me a sample code. Thanks in advance..

Comment: To call ps1 from C# it's explain on other post ==>https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/ 
https://www.google.com/search?q=execting+powershell+script+from+C%23+code&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: That copy of psexec.exe is not a happy one.  A basic way to trigger the exception is to deploy the 64-bit version of it on a 32-bit machine.  Or it just got mangled on the way to that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Install Power Shell in the Remote PC
Enable Power Shell Remoting to execute Powershell Commnads on the remote server by using the command "Enable-PSRemoting"
Add the server from which you are making the call as a Trusted one by using the command-
set-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value 172.16.0.0
```

NOTE :    Make Sure you run the above commands in both the computers

```
Now use the below code in your project to execute exe on remote server


  Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
  runspace.Open();
  Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
  ps.Commands.AddScript("$User = \"domain\\username\"");
  ps.Commands.AddScript("$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String \"yourpassword\" - 
  AsPlainText -Force");
  ps.Commands.AddScript("$Credential = New-Object -TypeName 
  System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord");
  ps.Commands.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTECOMPUTERIP -ScriptBlock { 
  D:\\TestApp.exe } -cred $Credential");

  Collection<PSObject> resultst = ps.Invoke();
                Collection<ErrorRecord> errors = ps.Streams.Error.ReadAll();
                StringBuilder errorDetails = new StringBuilder();
                if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (ErrorRecord er in errors)
                    {
                        errorDetails.AppendLine(er.Exception.ToString());

                    }
                    throw new Exception(errorDetails.ToString());
                }

                Console.WriteLine(errorDetails.ToString());
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (PSObject obj in resultst)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
                }`enter code here`
                Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
                runspace.Close();
```

Comment: By running the power shell commands and adding the above code in my project I can make the remote calls to the server.